# Apache flink - How to make sourcefunctions wait for backfilling state

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We use flink to enrich our data streams by using a connected stream.

For example: Our datastream might be taxi rides and our enrichment might be taxi drivers.

Think a topology like this:

```
BroadcastStream<TaxiDrivers> taxiDrivers = env.addSource(enrichments)
                                              .broadcast(MAP_DESCRIPTOR)

env.addSource(taxiRidesSource())
   .connect(taxiDrivers)
   .process(enrichWithTaxiDrivers())
   .output(someOutput())
```

If for some reason we should lose our Flink State we can republish the messages to the taxiDriver source to restore the state again.

**So what is going wrong?**

The problem when backfilling our state like this occurs when new taxiRides arrive before we're done backfilling the state.

We've thought about buffering in the enrichment in the `enrichWithTaxiDrivers()` function, or extending our source functions to `pause` but neither feels like a clean solution.

What would be a good way of having the mainstream (taxi rides) wait or pause until the backfilling has been completed?

Comment: Why not initialize the taxi drivers as a state in the process function?  IMO, you want to attribute the driver and the ride, which means you will have the drivers in the process function anyway.

Comment: @JiayiLiao That is what I want to do. So a TaxiDriver message would be sent once and stored in state. Then read multiple times for each TaxiRide. The trouble is when I want to rebuild the state. How can I make sure the taxi rides are 'held' back until all TaxiDrivers are in state again.

Comment: @richard-deurwaarder hello! did you find a way to implement this?

Comment: @Rocel I haven't, we ended up adding pause functionality on our sources and whenever we need to do an initial load we basically pause our entire job